# MySQL Insert Corruption

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, freetds

We're trying to pull data from MS SQL Server using the FreeTDS driver for PDO and inserting it into a MySQL table. However, it seems that one record is being populated with the correct data followed by a string of junk characters and even **portions of other queries**. We were able to replicate by re-importing the same record and each time it included different junk data.

Has anyone else run into this type of odd behavior? What could cause this?

The code basically boils down to selecting an NVARCHAR fields from SQL Server and inserting it into a VARCHAR fields in MySQL. For example:

SQL Server:

```
SELECT ItemName FROM Items;
```

returns 'gat43C4533'

MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO Items (ItemName) VALUES ('gat43C4533');
```

the result in the MySQL table is

```
gat43?4533 -*[$%^&^%#$^%&]                . CASE WHEN GHYT.Test...
```

Is there any way PDO could throw some type of error or handle this gracefully without populating the field with junk?

Is there any way this could be a bug in MySQL, or FreeTDS? No one has addressed the fact that random SQL code is showing up. Since it seems to be trying to insert some unreadable data could there be some memory issue where data is being returned from some random memory location? Or there is memory corruption?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show your code.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data that causes the corruption and queries?

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps you need to include the parenthesis around the values. I've never seen it done without: `INSERT INTO Items (ItemName) VALUES ('gat43C4533')`

Comment: I made a typo in the SQL, it's properly formatted in the file. I don't think the code itself would be helpful as it's just two queries. One fetches all of the items from SQL Server, then the items are looped through and inserted into the MySQL table. There is no additional formatting or data manipulation.

Comment: Probably there's some special character there you can't see, an unprintable character like a non-printing unicode char Or a linefeed without carriages return.

Comment: Thanks developerwjk. We eventually fixed it by retyping the value in SQL server. The C character was simply replaced by another C.

Comment: You sure that is "C"... it could be Cyrillic capital "S" which looks exactly like latin capital "C". In that case and with no proper encoding used, it easily results as "?" in database. According to your name Cyrillic letters aren't something strange to you, right?

Comment: I'm suspicious of codepage and charset issues here -- as if one database gives you double byte strings and the other isn't set up to handle them, or some such...

Comment: That might have something to do with it @RobP. I have the hex codes for the string that worked (0x6700610074003400330043003400350033003300) and the string that caused the error (0x6700610074003400330021043400350033003300).  There is definitely something strange about the 'C'. It shows up properly in SQL server, but it's not the standard character it seems.

Comment: @IlyaRogov those are definitely double-byte char strings, the '4300' is an ASCII 'C' and the 2104 is not representable as a single-byte ASCII char. Is the column you are selecting from utf8?

Comment: The collation of the database is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. So I'm guessing that it's not using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I have confirmed that the character that is being inserted and causing the issue is a Cyrillic 'С'. Why does MySQL freak out though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what the issue was.

The character causing the error was a Cyrillic C.

The PDO connection to MySQL did not specify the UTF-8 encoding so I added:

```
$PDOconnection->exec("set names utf8");
```

That allowed the special character to be inserted without an issue.

The random SQL and junk data that was being displayed in the terminal was likely due to the EOT character being in the inserted string.

Answer (score 1):

try using this to clean the string before inserting.
it will remove special characters that cannot be seen, example \n

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.

   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the item names can have non alpha-numeric characters in them including spaces, dashes, and even question marks (weird right?!). Ideally, I'd need something to prevent any non-decodeable, non-utf-8 characters from going in.

Comment: We will test this out today. Thanks.

Comment: None of the iconv conversions seem to work properly. The value shows up fine everywhere except for MySQL where it displays as garbage.